# IAR change default project settings

Tags: embedded, microcontroller, msp430, iar

I just got IAR and am creating a bunch of new projects for different tutorials i am following but it is making me change the project settings for each project i make and i see now way to set up default project settings.

Is there a way to change it so that I can set my default target to MSP430F5529, default compiler optimizations to none, default Driver in Debugger to FET Debugger, and add a path to my default include locations?

Comment: So, you bought this expensive toolchain and do not even get support?

Comment: called support, their answer was "just make a new workspace each time and manually do it"

Comment: Yes, that sounds familar. FYI: gcc mainline does support the MSP430 since 4.9 :-) The only thing I did regret when I used gcc (the fork back then) instead of IAR was that I did not earlier ... Just have a look at SCons for build system. No GUI, but I do not miss that either.